# UISwitch thumbTintColor removes shadow

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I'm creating an app that has a UISwitch. I changed the thumb color to match the background (using `thumbTintColor`) and the shadow on the thumb is removed. The result is the thumb vanishing when it is in the off position.

Does anyone know how to add a shadow to the thumb, or prevent it from going away?

Comment: Yup this is a bug on Apple's part - changing the thumbTintColor from default removes the shadow immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific, paste some code, what I understand is, you are trying to do something like these:

```
self.switch1.thumbTintColor = self.switch1.backgroundColor;
```

But I guess this question has more than a year, probably should be deleted by a moderator :)

Bye!